# Group results from different tables by rank

Tags: mysql, grouping, ranking

I'm sure I'm not the first to need to do this, but I couldn't find a similar question that accounted for the nuance.

I have 3 tables (**fav_food**, **fav_color**, and **fav_place**) that all follow a similar pattern:

```
userid   |   label    |  rank   |
=================================
1        | red        | 1
1        | green      | 2
1        | orange     | 3
2        | blue       | 1
2        | red        | 2
...
```

Each table will have at most 3 items per userid, **but some users might have fewer than 3, and other users might have none** for a given table. i.e., it's possible user 10 has 2 favorite colors, 1 favorite food, and 0 favorite places.

I'm looking for a query that can output my data like so:

```
userid  |   fav_food  |  fav_place  |  fav_color  |  rank
===========================================================
1       | pizza       | New York    | red         | 1 
1       | burgers     | NULL        | green       | 2
1       | NULL        | NULL        | orange      | 3
2       | tacos       | Chicago     | blue        | 1
2       | burgers     | Orlando     | red         | 2
...
```

Basically, all ranked 1 items together, ranked 2 items together, and ranked 3 items together (NULLs were no item of that rank exists).

I was able to get it working using 3 separate queries (one for each table) + post processing at the application layer, but for the sake of my personal knowledge base, I was wondering if anyone knew how to do it in a single query.

Many thanks!

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN ON userid and rank

Comment: @PM77-1 That's going to give me a result set of all combinations of tuples, but I'd need to further reduce that by matching rank while accounting for nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Isick,

You can do this with a LEFT OUTER JOIN on each table to a table containing just the userid and rank.  [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8e16d/7)

```
 select user_rank.userid, user_rank.rank, f.food, p.place, c.color from 
 (
    select userid, rank from fav_food
    union
    select userid, rank from fav_place
    union
    select userid, rank from fav_color
    ) user_rank
left outer join 
( select userid, rank, label as food from fav_food) f
on user_rank.userid = f.userid and user_rank.rank = f.rank
left outer join 
( select userid, rank, label as place from fav_place) p
on user_rank.userid = p.userid and user_rank.rank = p.rank
left outer join 
( select userid, rank, label as color from fav_color) c
on user_rank.userid = c.userid and user_rank.rank = c.rank
order by userid, rank
```

Comment: Appreciate you responding. The inner query + union was key. I ended up encorporating a group by rank and userid with null fill and MAX() to avoid selecting on the rank tables a second time. Your response is much appreciated. Thank you!